# Nextjs api endpoint fails with 'UND_ERR_REQ_CONTENT_LENGTH_MISMATCH'

Tags: next.js, next.js13

I am trying to create the simplest possible endpoint using the /pages/api/hello.ts route.

I am using Nextjs 13.4.19. Any ideas why this is failing and how to fix it?

Here is my code

```js
import { NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from 'next';

export default (req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse) => {
    res.status(200).json({ text: 'Hello' });
};
```

I am getting the following error:

```js
TypeError: fetch failed
    at Object.fetch (node:internal/deps/undici/undici:11576:11)
    at async invokeRequest (C:\Users\gyurisc\dev\projects\audio-genie\node_modules\next\dist\server\lib\server-ipc\invoke-request.js:17:12)
    at async invokeRender (C:\Users\gyurisc\dev\projects\audio-genie\node_modules\next\dist\server\lib\router-server.js:254:29)
    at async requestHandler (C:\Users\gyurisc\dev\projects\audio-genie\node_modules\next\dist\server\lib\router-server.js:475:24)
    at async Server.<anonymous> (C:\Users\gyurisc\dev\projects\audio-genie\node_modules\next\dist\server\lib\start-server.js:117:13) {
  cause: RequestContentLengthMismatchError: Request body length does not match content-length header
      at write (C:\Users\gyurisc\dev\projects\audio-genie\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\undici\index.js:1:67105)
      at _resume (C:\Users\gyurisc\dev\projects\audio-genie\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\undici\index.js:1:66726)
      at resume (C:\Users\gyurisc\dev\projects\audio-genie\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\undici\index.js:1:65413)
      at connect (C:\Users\gyurisc\dev\projects\audio-genie\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\undici\index.js:1:65301) {
    code: 'UND_ERR_REQ_CONTENT_LENGTH_MISMATCH'
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out. It seems that from NextJS 13.2 the API endpoints are changed. Now you need to create the following file:

/app/api/hello/route.ts

instead of simply adding the hello.ts under the API folder.

for reference here is the simple API endpoint I defined for testing:

```js
// /app/api/hello/route.ts
import { NextRequest, NextResponse } from "next/server";

export async function GET(request: NextRequest) {
    let response = {
        status: 200,
        text: "Hello",
        field: "Some other value"
    };


    return NextResponse.json(response);
}


export async function POST(request: Request) {
    try {
        const json = await request.json();
        return NextResponse.json(json);
    } catch (error: any) {
        return NextResponse.json(error);
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you stating that the pages/api/ routes are giving problems? I'm getting the same error using pages/api/[endpoint_name] route and have been putting off transitioning to the app router.

Comment: Yes, I believe so so. If you try the code above it should work